It should be possible to require major changes based on someone else's review-less comment
I.e at https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78619629 there was a previous comment which elaborated major changes that are required. I should be able to mark it as such based on that comment rather than having to post my own dummy comment.

In many cases, the reviewers aren't used to the Staging Ground and the UX makes them forget. If that happens, it might also be a good idea to inform the other reviewer about the "Requires Major Changes" option, either in a reply or via chat.SO.

Regarding the review there though, the new editor which the staging ground uses doesn't have stack snippets. If that's the only feedback you have you might want to publish and edit instead.

I will actually downvote this. the reason being that I don't support changes which are intended to circumvent having to communicate and inform people of mistakes they are making by sort of "auto-correcting" badly made choices, like in this case posting a comment which should have been a review action. No do communicate. Please. The more effort is involved, the better. For now.

Sorry, what? How was I circumventing having to communicate here?

I am against reviewing by just upvoting another reviewer's comment. However, if the previous comment is left without a review, while I still think dan's idea of reminding the commenter is better, I am not against reviewing by upvoting such prior comment (but the prior comment can only be used for a single time). The distinction is IMHO not very clear in the question.

"How was I circumventing having to communicate here?" - What you are suggesting would provide a way to do precisely that.  (Even if you don't intended to use it that way.)  And I would posit that saying "XXX's comments must be addressed" is not a dummy comment.  It is providing clear direction to the OP; i.e. a real communication.  (It is also a communication to re-reviewers.  Implicitly ... "please check that the OP has fixed >this<".)
